# Script to run on Gentoo Linux after computer crash

Tags: linux

Is there a script file which is run after a system crash when system starts. We need to run a special Database repair script if the server crashes (because of the power outage for example).

What would also help is some way of detecting a server crash at startup.

Thanks!

Comment: migrate to serverfault! migrate to serverfault!

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Is there a way to move it?

Comment: nah, don't worry about it.  I said if have jokingly, I dont like the site fragmentation too much, but this one is actually sort of ok to migrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gentoo has a directory `/etc/local.d` for scripts which will be run at system startup (if the filename ends with `.start`) and normal shutdown (if it ends with `.stop`). Off the top of my head I would suggest something like the following:

- Create a `.stop` script which creates an empty file somewhere, to use as an indicator of a normal shutdown
- Create a `.start` script which checks for the presence of the file and runs the DB repair script if it isn't found, or deletes it if it is found

I'm assuming that your database repair script won't cause any problems if it is run on an uncorrupted database.

Comment: This would be a good trick. Thanks. I was hoping for a /etc/crash.d or something.